# Android Studio How To Set Constraints And Use LayoutParams Dynamically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, layoutparams

In my Android Application I want to create a bunch of `ConstraintLayouts` where each has for example an `ImageView` and a `TextView` in them.

Everything is created from code exept for one `TableRow` with which I will start out. My Problem ist that despite being able to set the margins via LayoutParams for the `ConstraintLayout`, the `ImageView` and the `TextView` do not change at all when I try to set the margins.

```
public fun generateAsset(tableRow: TableRow) {
    // <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    //     android:layout_margin="4dp"
    //     android:background="@drawable/x32_tile_dark">

    val clayout = ConstraintLayout(context)
    tableRow.addView(clayout)
    val cparams = clayout.layoutParams as TableRow.LayoutParams
    cparams.setMargins(4, 4, 4, 4) // <--- Works correctly!
    clayout.layoutParams = cparams
    clayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.x32_tile_dark)

    // <ImageView
    //     android:layout_width="0dp"
    //     android:layout_height="60dp"
    //     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    //     app:srcCompat="@drawable/x256_spaceship_door_gray_blue" />

    val iView = ImageView(context)
    clayout.addView(iView)
    val iparams = iView.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
    iparams.width = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    iparams.height = 200
    iparams.setMargins(8, 8, 8, 8) // <--- Does not do anything!
    iView.layoutParams = iparams
    iView.setImageResource(R.drawable.x256_spaceship_door_gray_blue)

    // <TextView
    //     android:text="Massive Spaceship Door"
    //     android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    //     android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    //     android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    //     android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    val ntext = TextView(context)
    clayout.addView(ntext)
    val nparams = ntext.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
    nparams.setMargins(8, 8, 8, 8) // <--- Does not do anything!
    ntext.layoutParams = nparams
    ntext.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
    ntext.text = assetName
}
```

The reason why this doesn't work is probably because I haven't set the constraints of the `ImageView` and the `TextView` but how do I do that in code?

The `ImageView` should be right in the center of the `ConstraintLayout` while the `TextView` is supposed to be in the center but at the bottom.

How can I set the constraints to do what I've described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right to suspect that not setting the constraints may be the issue. To set constraints programmatically take a look at [**ConstraintSet**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet).

> This class allows you to define programmatically a set of constraints to be used with ConstraintLayout. It lets you create and save constraints, and apply them to an existing ConstraintLayout.

As an added bonus, **ConstraintSet** permits the setting of margins while setting constraints.

There are some good tutorials online about how to use **ConstraintSet**.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure here, but i have a suggestion and believe you have to call
`iView .updateMargins<ConstraintLayout.LayoutParama>{//do some stuff here}`.

You probably ask "Why?".
Well, i think its because you already created `val clayout = ConstraintLayout(context)` but didnt specify which attributesSet it has, thus taking the default one. And since your View already has defaultParams, they need to be updated now.

But please do some independet reasearch or ask a real expert with real knowledge. Because i am not really sure and this is just some suggestion.